# Robots.txt disallow all except one directory and access to sitemap

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

robots.txt containts following instructions:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /public/
Disallow: /
Sitemap: http://sitedomain.com/sitemapindex.xml
```

it seems that in this case `sitemapindex` won't be accessible for the search crawler and should be moved to `public` folder, is it correct or crawler will process the sitemap in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sitemapindex` won't be accessible for the search crawler and should be moved to `public` folder

Yes, that is correct, the XML sitemap won't be crawlable unless moved to the `/public/` folder.

Alternatively, you could add an exception for your sitemap:

```
Allow: /sitemapindex.xml
```